# finding records where belongs_to table's column is not equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Trainer model that has a has_many relationship with Pokemon. How do I find all Trainers who do not have any Pokemon of a certain type or group of types(type is a column in Pokemon model)?

The code I have tried, but it returns a trainer if any of his Pokemon's types is not in the group (e.g. if a trainer has pokemon of type fire and electric, he will be returned because electric isn't in the array. I don't want him returned because he has a fire pokemon.)

```
Trainer.joins(:pokemons).where("pokemons.type NOT IN (?)", ["fire","grass","water"])
```

The same problem occurs when I'm just comparing to one type.

```
Trainer.joins(:pokemons).where("pokemons.type != ?", "fire")
```

Again, the example trainer will get returned because he has a pokemon with a type, electric, that is not equal to fire.

I am using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to write this with Rails in one query, but you can do the following:

```
Trainer.where('trainers.id NOT IN (?)', Pokemon.where(type: ['grass', 'fire', 'water']).pluck(:trainer_id).uniq )
```

Explained version:

```
# selects the IDs of Trainer having a Pokemon of type Grass||Fire||Water
trainer_ids = Pokemon.where(type: ['grass', 'fire', 'water']).pluck(:trainer_id)
# returns the trainers
Trainer.where('trainers.id NOT IN (?)', trainer_ids)
```

Comment: holah buckets sir. you have answered my question yet again. you are a lord among serfs. May your sword stay sharp and your steed be quick.

Comment: It is always a pleasure to help you!

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4, you can do:

```
Trainer.where.not(id: Pokemons.select(:trainer_id).where("pokemons.type IN (?)", ["fire","grass","water"])
```

This will grab all the trainers where their id does not show up in the list of trainer_ids on pokemons with fire, grass, or water.

Comment: sorry I should have said my version. I'm using rails 3.2.13.

Comment: @Mattherick I tried it. I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`. When I remove `not`, it does fine in retrieving all trainers who have do pokemon types in the  given group.

Comment: not is only available in rails 4, so yeah, it won't work in 3.2.13. If you don't want to or can't upgrade rails, then you can make this work but you have to do more SQL. The idea is the same, just do a standard where but use the quote version like in the subselect I showed. it would be Trainer.where("id not in (select trainer_id from pokemons where type in (?))", ["fire","grass","water"])

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is doing the query on the SQL layer through ActiveRecord's find_by_sql:

```
Trainer.find_by_sql [
  "SELECT * FROM trainers
  WHERE id NOT IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT(trainers.id) FROM
  trainers JOIN pokemons
  ON trainers.id = pokemons.trainer_id
  WHERE pokemons.type IN ('grass', 'fire','water'))"
]
```